# elasticsearch: can I index a document and contextually execute a percolator query, hence got results within the server answer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

this is my scenario:

- a index of percolate queries (with a suitable schema of the document to act upon)
- a index of documents

when I'm indexing a document, can I also execute a percolate query againsta this data so in the server answer (that usually is the indexed document) I get along also the result of the query?

I'm trying to see if I can execute insert and query in a "transaction" instead of two server calls: one for indexing and one for the query.

Asking this because while searching for the percolator query feature I stumbled upon a lot of legacy code (ES version wise) and while reading got a glimpse of a querystring parameters about _percolate-something that could be me something about that, then I lost it and was not able to find an answer to this question by reading the documentation.

THX